# How to Fetch google APi array

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps

I want to fetch  Postcode   [ "long_name" : "S35 1TZ",]   from this google api array

Iam usin this API

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=(53.4624118,%20-1.4922259999999596)

Using
msg.results[0].address_components[6].long_name;
Not working

```
{
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "7A",
                   "short_name" : "7A",
                   "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Hollow Gate",
                   "short_name" : "Hollow Gate",
                   "types" : [ "route" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Chapeltown",
                   "short_name" : "Chapeltown",
                   "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Sheffield",
                   "short_name" : "Sheffield",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Sheffield",
                   "short_name" : "Sheffield",
                   "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "South Yorkshire",
                   "short_name" : "South York",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
                   "short_name" : "GB",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "S35 1TZ",
                   "short_name" : "S35 1TZ",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "7A Hollow Gate, Sheffield, South Yorkshire S35 1TZ, UK",
             "geometry" : {
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : 53.4624118,
                   "lng" : -1.492226
                },
                "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 53.4637607802915,
                      "lng" : -1.490877019708498
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 53.4610628197085,
                      "lng" : -1.493574980291502
                   }
                }
             },
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

Comment: Even though the code is not correct, mind that `6` should be `7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. Based on your code, I am not sure if you got a string of that data or already an object. If you only got data back, it is a string and you first have to convert the JSON into PHP array or object.

1 - You could convert the JSON to an array:

```
$msg = json_decode($msg,true);

/* And call it by */
echo($msg['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name']);
```

OR

2 - Using the object notation:

```
$msg = json_decode($msg);

/* And call it by */
echo($msg->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name);
```

If you got the data back using a Google API PHP libary, it's probably not a string but an object so you can dismiss the `json_decode()` and use option 2. If you want to prefer using option 1, you can cast the object into an array by using `$msg = (array)$msg;`

In general using `print_r($msg)` or `var_dump($msg)` can be handy to debug the thing, just add your path each time you get closer to your goal. So in this case `var_dump($msg)` then `var_dump($msg->result)`, then `var_dump($msg->result[0])`, and so on.